# Logical operation inside String.Equals parameter

Tags: c#, string

I'm receiving a packet from a device that is word in size (2 bytes). It is either 0 or 1 in value, based on the datasheet of the device. I'm not sure yet if it throws just "0"/"1" or "00"/"01" in string, hence the code.

```
bool isErrorRet = packet.Substring(6, 2).Equals("0" || "00");
```

Is that a valid code?

PS. I'm coding using Notepad++, I don't have an IDE installed (yet).

Comment: If you code something more than HelloWorld then I guess it's more time consuming to edit in Notepad++ than to install Visual Studio

Comment: @PiotrWolkowski I uninstalled VS2008 few days ago to have VS2012 installed, but I forgot to. I have to code my part (a DLL) in our project today and I can't afford to waste time on installation, that's why I have to resort to Notepad++ for now. My groupmates have VS installed so they can check if my code is working or not. The methods I'm doing in DLL are fairly simple though (no threading or async, etc).

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_csharp_online.php

While it doesn't support intellisense at least you can compile and execute your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the equality as two separate .Equals() call with a logical operator:

```
bool isErrorRet = packet.Substring(6, 2).Equals("0") || packet.Substring(6,2).Equals("00");
```

If you attempt to use your code, you will receive the following compiler error:

> Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and
>   'string'

This error is returned since the || operator can only be applied as [follows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx).

> The conditional-OR operator (||) performs a logical-OR of its bool
>   operands. If the first operand evaluates to true, the second operand
>   isn't evaluated. If the first operand evaluates to false, the second
>   operator determines whether the OR expression as a whole evaluates to
>   true or false.

In your case, .Equals expects an explicit value of string type, not a logical-OR operator, which is all you are passing.

Comment: "I can if I can, can I?"  in the face of being told "You can't," is pretty novel.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot The original answer is up to the second line only. The time that I commented that, there was no clear explanation if the code is valid or not.

Comment: @DavidL Thank you for the elaboration.

Comment: The original answer is "if you try to use your code you'll receive this error." The error is erroneously referred to as an exception instead of a compiler error, but  the original post more than answers the question of "can i do this."

Comment: @PrestonGuillot whoops, great call.  Updated

Answer (score 1):

That is not valid code. If you try to compile it, it will fail. Instead you will have to use the equals call twice:

```
String s =  packet.Substring(6, 2);
bool isErrorRet = s.Equals("0") || s.Equals("00");
```